# Uniqueness of the extension in Hahn-Kolmogorov extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Statement:** (Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem) Every pre-measure $\mu_0 : \mathcal{B}_0\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ on a Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}_0$ in $X$ can be extended to a countably additive measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$.

Outline for proof of the **existence** is the following,

construct the outer measure $\mu^*:2^X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$
$$\mu^*(E) := \inf\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(E_n) : E\subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n; E_n\in \mathcal{B}_0\},$$
then applying the **Caratheodory extension theorem** that the set of $\mu^*$-measurable sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and by restricting $\mu^*$ to $\mathcal{B}$ we get the countably additive measure $\mu:\mathcal{B} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$. At last, check that $\mathcal{B}$ contains $\mathcal{B}_0$ and $\mu(E) = \mu_0(E)$ for $E\in \mathcal{B}_0$, in another word $\mu$ extends $\mu_0$.

For **uniqueness**, if $\mu_0$ is $\sigma$-finite, for two extensions of $\mu_0$, namely $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and $\mu':\mathcal{B}'\rightarrow [0,\infty]$, we have $\mu(E) = \mu'(E)$ for all $E\in \mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{B}'$.

> My first question where does the non-uniqueness come from? From different outer measures? Or from the Caratheodory extension
>   theorem which extends the outer measure to a measure? This is not clear from the existence proof. If the outer measure is unique, is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\mu^*$-measurable sets the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which the extension can be done? So all the extensions would agree on this smallest $\sigma$-algebra. Just like Lebesgue measure on Lebesgue measurable sets and Lebesgue measure on Borel sets are both extensions of the elementary measure on $\sigma$(elementary sets) , in this case, is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that we can work with for the extension.

To prove this, it suffices to show that given an extension $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$, for any other measure $\nu$ defined on $\mathcal{B}$ which agrees with $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{B}_0$, we have $\nu(E) = \mu^*(E)$ for $E\in \mathcal{B}$, or to say $\nu = \mu$ on $\mathcal{B}$.

> Is the above argument sufficient? This is something that I read in a
>   note which hinted it would imply this kind of uniqueness. From what I understand, there is a measure on $\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{B}'$ which is an extension of $\mu_0$, since both $\mu$ and $\mu'$ can be restricted to this $\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{B}'$, we would get the desired result.

1. For $\nu \leq \mu^*$, observe that for each collection $\{E_n\}$ such that $E\subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n; E_n\in \mathcal{B}_0$, we have
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(E_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n) \geq \nu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n)\geq \nu(E),$$
   since taking the infinum does not change the inequality, we have $\nu(E) \leq\mu^*(E)$.
2. For $\nu\geq\mu^*$, first assume that $\mu^*(E) <\infty$ so that we can apply an "$\epsilon$" argument, then we generalize the result which uses the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu_0$. To prove $\nu(E)\geq\mu^*(E)$, it suffices to show $\nu(E)\geq\mu^*(E)-\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$. Let $\epsilon$ be given, we know there exists disjoint $\{E_n\}, E_n \in \mathcal{B}_0$ such that 
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(E_n) \leq \mu^*(E) +\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$ 
   using the fact that $\mu_0 (E_n) = \nu(E_n)$, $\nu$ is countability additive and (1), we have 
   $$\nu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n / E) \leq \mu^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n / E)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Also use the fact that 
$$\nu(\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) =\mu^*(\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) $$
for each finite $N$ together with there exists $N$ such that 
$$\mu^*(\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) \geq \mu^*(E) - \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$
we have
$$\nu(E) \geq \nu (\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) -\frac{\epsilon}{2} \geq \nu (\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) -\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \mu^* (\cup_{n=1}^N E_n) -\frac{\epsilon}{2}\geq \mu^*(E) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Now for the case when $\mu^*(E) = \infty$, cover $E$ with $A_n \in\mathcal{B}_0$ which all have finite $\mu_0$ measure and define $G_k = \cup_{n=1}^k A_k$, we have
$$\nu (E\cap G_k) \geq \mu^*(E\cap G_k)$$
for all $k$. Letting $k$ tends to infinity, $\mu^*(E\cap G_k)$ goes to infinity, then $\nu (E\cap G_k)$ goes to infinity as well$.

> Last, could you guys check my proof please. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't really feel like reading the entire question, but for a counter-example to uniqueness without finiteness assumptions, consider $\mu_0([0,1/n])=\infty=\mu_0((1/n,1])$ (in the boolean algebra generated by those intervals in $[0,1]$). Then $\mu(\{0\})$ can be literally anything in $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, but even with the $\sigma$-finiteness, the extension is only unique within its own $\sigma$-algebra; my question is mainly where does this non-uniqueness come from.

Comment: The extension is unique in the following sense: If $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two extensions to $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ respectively, then
$$
\mu_1\left.\right|_{\mathcal{B}} = \mu_2\left.\right|_{\mathcal{B}}
$$
where $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}_1\cap \mathcal{B}_2$

Comment: Yes, but where did the $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ come from? Because in the existence proof, it only used the $\sigma$-algebra which is generated by $\mu^*$-measurable sets, is this the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which the extension can be done? And in general where does the non-uniqueness come from? different outer measures or the extension from an outer measure to a measure?

Comment: @I believe that the uniqueness is for *any* extension at all (even to larger $\sigma$-algebras). About uniqueness, unless I've made some mistake, if you look at the example I cited, the measure of an extension does *not* have to agree with the outer measure (you could put $\mu(\{0\})=0$ while $\mu_0^*(\{0\})=\infty$). The measure you obtain by simple Caratheodory completion is unique by its very construction. It is canonical.